# Can't initialize the radio button in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

please look into my code.

The code I was using is

```
<md-radio-group ng-model = "accepted" layout = "row">
   <md-radio-button ng-value = 1>
        Accepted
   </md-radio-button>
   <md-radio-button ng-value = 0>
        Rejected
   </md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

and the js code is `$scope.accepted = ($scope.status.accepted) ? '1': '0';`
this was working fine for me.

but, I wanted to change the code like below, used meaningful string instead of 1 and 0. 
after changing, the radio button not working, i cannot initialize the button, and even when clicking on it, both radio button is got selected.

the below is changed code, and currently using

```
<md-radio-group ng-model = "accepted" layout = "row">
   <md-radio-button ng-value = 'User_Accepted'>
        Accepted
   </md-radio-button>
   <md-radio-button ng-value = 'User_Rejected'>
        Rejected
   </md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

and in my js, I

```
$scope.accepted = ($scope.status.accepted) ? 'User_Accepted': 'User_Rejected';
```

Comment: In your original code, ng-value = 0 (no quotes), in your second code it now has quotes around the values.

Comment: first code is working properly, and in second code I used string. so I should give single quotes , right?

Comment: Could you do up a quick plunker with the example so I can take a look and help you fix it?